# humanoid_nav_msgs not found while building nao_virtual

Tags: gazebo, catkin-make, ros-indigo, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I'm a totally ROS rookie and I have the following problem:

- It's my aim to simulate Nao in Gazebo using plain ros_control architecture.

See also: (https://github.com/ros-naoqi/nao_virtual)

- My procedure:

1. I create a Workspace (catkin workspace)

   mkdir -p ~/nao_ws/src
   cd ~/nao_ws/src
   catkin_init_workspace
   cd~/catkin_ws
   catkin_make
2. Subsequently:

   cd  ~/nao_ws/src
   git clone https://github.com/roboticsgroup/roboticsgroup_gazebo_plugins.git
   git clone https://github.com/pal-robotics/pal_msgs.git
   git clone https://github.com/pal-robotics/pal_gazebo_plugins.git
   catkin_make

`catkin_make` command produced the following error:

```
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "humanoid_nav_msgs"
  with any of the following names:

    humanoid_nav_msgsConfig.cmake
    humanoid_nav_msgs-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "humanoid_nav_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "humanoid_nav_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "humanoid_nav_msgs" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  pal_msgs/pal_walking_msgs/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)


-- Could not find the required component 'humanoid_nav_msgs'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "humanoid_nav_msgs"
  with any of the following names:

    humanoid_nav_msgsConfig.cmake
    humanoid_nav_msgs-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "humanoid_nav_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "humanoid_nav_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "humanoid_nav_msgs" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  pal_msgs/pal_walking_msgs/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/name/nao_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/name/nao_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

---

My Ubuntu version: 14.04 (Indigo)

Can anybody help me further?

Many thanks and best regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281671/humanoid_nav_msgs-not-found-while-building-nao_virtual/) by [BoC](https://answers.ros.org/users/33539/boc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2018-02-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-02-02**:
Do you have the `humanoid_nav_msgs` package?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-03**:
@BoC: I've changed the title of your question, as your problem does not seem to be with "simulating nao in gazebo using plain ros_control". At least not yet. The problem is getting the packages to compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The readme in the repository you link seems to be slightly incomplete.

Unless the packages you cloned to your workspace are completely stand-alone / self-sufficient (which almost no pkg is, as reuse is one of the corner stones of ROS), you'll have to make sure that you have *all dependencies* of those packages installed on your system as well.

ROS has a tool for that, called `rosdep`. See #q215059 for an explanation why ROS introduced a 'new tool', and see #q252478 that uses the tool in an example workflow that builds a pkg cloned from a repository.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2018-02-24**:
As these dependencies are not needed by this package anymore, a PR has been opened to update the readme accordingly https://github.com/ros-naoqi/nao_virtual/pull/24